# htaccess rules to redirect in the same directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new in htaccess rules. I have tried to search about my question but couldn't get the answer.

I have got a url like this  `mysite.it/test/libro/la-missione-cristiana/1959` and I would like to rewrite to `mysite.it/test/index.php?page=libro&id=1959`

I have the following htaccess file in my root folder and I have added the following line:

```
RewriteRule ^test/libro/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+) test/index.php?page=libro&id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

but It doesn't work.

I would really appreciate if someone could explain me the cause.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

your match all but slash group '([^/.]+)' appears to *group all non-slash and non-any-character*, thus it will not match anything as the . matches any, and the plus require at least one match.

try remove the dots

```
RewriteRule ^test/libro/([^/]+)/([^/]+) test/index.php?page=libro&id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

should work for you.

Comment: This is incorrect. A dot `.` within a character class `[]` is not a special character any more.

Comment: I thank you. Now It matches  and you solve my problem. I have moved the line at the top of my .htaccess file.